# Swift - Expecting a leak after strongly capturing self in closure

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, closures, retain-cycle, strong-references

Can anyone please explain why this doesn't leak?

I'm capturing `self` within a `closure` so I would have two strong pointers pointing at each other, therefore, the `deinit` message shouldn't ever be called for the Person object.

First, this is my class **Person**:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}
```

And this is my **ViewController's implementation**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var john:Person?

    func callClosureFunction( closure:(name:Bool) -> () ) {
        closure(name: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        john = Person(name:"John")

        self.callClosureFunction { (name) in

            self.john?.name = "John Appleseed"
            self.john = nil

            // xcode prints - John Appleseed is being deinitialized
        }

    }

}
```

I was expecting to be able to fix the issue by doing:

```
self.callClosureFunction { [weak self] (name) in ...
```

But that wasn't even necessary. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your view controller is not *retaining* the closure, there is no circular reference.  If you wrote this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var john:Person?
    var closure:(Bool)->()? 

    func callClosureFunction( closure:((name:Bool) -> ())? ) {
        closure?(name: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        john = Person(name:"John")
        closure = { (name) in

            self.john?.name = "John Appleseed"    

            // Because this closure will never be released, the instance of Person will never deinit either
        }
        self.callClosureFunction(closure) 
    }  
}
```

then the view controller would retain the closure and the closure would retain the view controller via its reference to `self`. Therefore, neither would be released, and if you don't explicitly set `self.john = nil` (which you did in your original example), then the `Person` instance would never get `deninit` called.

It's quite common to inappropriately use weak `self` in closures when not necessary (and this can actually lead to some obscure bugs). The key rule to remember is that weak references are not the default in general under ARC. Strong should be the default *unless it would lead to a retain cycle*, in which case weak should be used only to break that circular reference. Same for closures: strong `self` should be the default, *unless* the `self` in this case also has a strong reference to the closure itself.

Comment: the `John Appleseed` `Person` object will still deinit. See my answer

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov  If the closure retains the VC (self) and the VC retains the closure as in my example, then the VC never gets released (nor does the closure).  If the VC never deinits, then it never in turn releases its reference to the Person object, which means that the Person object would never deinit either.

Comment: Doesn't matter if there's a retain cycle. `john` is explicitly set to `nil`, removing the last reference, thus causing ARC to `deinit` it.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov  Oh right — good point that I missed. Updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're capturing `self` which points to `ViewController`, but you're wondering about the `Person` instance.

`Person` is actually not circular referenced and therefore gets de-initalized and released just fine when you set it to nil at the end of your closure.

Implement `deinit` for `ViewController` and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm capturing self within a closure so I would have two strong pointers pointing at each other, therefore, the deinit message shouldn't ever be called for the Person object.

No, you have one strong pointer, from the closure to `self`. There's no cyclic reference back from the closure to `self`. Thus, you have a [directed acylic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), which is no problem for ARC.

However, your experiment is flawed, from the get-go. Even if the closure was captured, the `John Appleseed` `Person` object would still `deinit`. This object's lifecycle is exclusively dependent on on the `john` reference from your `ViewController`. When you set that reference to `nil`, you're removing the last reference to the `John Appleseed` object, thus it's deinitialized.